# While viewing a PDF file, file is detected by any installed download manager rather than viewing it, how to overcome this behavior?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, pdf, cross-browser, download-manager

I'm using [jQuery Media Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/#overview) to embedded PDF into a web page as listed in the following [sample](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/misc.html) to ebmedded PDF files.
The problem is, if any download manager installed on client machine, it starts automatically downloading file rather than viewing it in web page which is not required.

I need to **force viewing of PDF file in page**. Is this can be achieved using Media plugin or any other plugins? or anyway which can be used within ASP.NET page and must be a cross browser solution.

**[Edit]**
* Converting PDF to images or using any flash viewer for embedding pdf is not preferred.
* Using Google Docs Viewer is not preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like overkill.  The ideal way is to just use the `<object>` tag to embed a pdf file in your markup.

For examples read this: http://pdfobject.com/

and this: http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/object-application.html#pdf

Comment: I tried PDFObject, it's the same issue. IDM (Internet Download Manager) starts automatically downloading file, which is not required.

Comment: If only it were that simple; In my experience, IE doesn't embed PDFs in a web page when using the `<object>` tag. (all other browsers seem to handle it fine, though)

Comment: @Andrew: agreed on this. Cross Browser functionality should be provided, so I cannot depended on <object> tag. Also, another issue, that in some browsers, <object> tag is captured by browser built-in download manager, which also is not required.

Comment: @Ahmed - it's possible the problem is with the download manager; It may be set to inject itself *always* to handle certain types of files, no matter what. Such a setting would be impossible to defeat from the server.

Answer (score 1):

There is another plug-in available for jQuery here:  http://dev.funkynerd.com/projects/jquery-pdfdoc

It uses the PDF.js library to render PDFs in JavaScript.